# AssetMaint_Extension; status still active when the Dispose action is pressed

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Page: Fixed Assets (FA303000)
I have an integration process running when FixedAsset_RowPersistedevent happens.

```
 protected void FixedAsset_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
     if (Base.Accessinfo.ScreenID == "FA.50.60.00") return;
     FixedAsset row = (FixedAsset)e.Row;
     if (Base.Asset.Cache.GetStatus(row) == PXEntryStatus.Deleted) return;

     DoIntegration();
    }
```

When the Actions >> **Dispose** button is clicked the FixedAsset_RowPersistedevent event is called but the status has not changed to disposed.

What is the best/right **event** to be used for my integration so that the status has changed to disposed.

Comment: Can you give sample of code you use? Do you call it via postman/fiddler?

Comment: Yuriy the integration does work, my question is regarding what event will be the best to use. I need the status field to be changed to disposed and then call an event to do the integration.

Comment: @YuriyZaletskyy I added the code and also restated the question hope it is a bit more clear

Comment: You want change status of Asset to disposed? Why not to call RunDisposal?